# ASP.NET Core 5, How to inject dependencies in SignalR Hub class?

Tags: asp.net-core, unit-of-work, abp

I am developing a IoT application using ABP vNext, by using the repository in the hub, but the connection is disposed. How should I inject dependencies correctly?

```
[Authorize(Roles = RoleResources.Collector)]
public class CollectorHub : AbpHub
{
    private readonly CollectorManager _manager;
    private readonly IRepository<Collector, Guid> _repository;
    private readonly ICacheManager<string, CollectorSession> _sessionCache;

    public CollectorHub(
        CollectorManager manager,
        IRepository<Collector, Guid> repository,
        ICacheManager<string, CollectorSession> sessionCache)
    {
        _manager = manager;
        _repository = repository;
        _sessionCache = sessionCache;
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception e)
    {
        var collectorId = GetCollectorId();
        var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
        _sessionCache.Remove(connectionId);

        ## ?? both repository and hub are transient, but the following line of code throws an error that the connection has been disposed!
        var collector = await _repository.FindAsync(collectorId);
        if (collector != null)
        {
            collector.CommunicationState = CommunicationState.Offline;
            await _repository.UpdateAsync(collector, true);
        }

        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(e);
    }
}
```

> System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
> at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
> at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /*/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 139
> at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.CreateSessionAsync(ConnectionPool pool, Int32 startTickCount, Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:line 892 at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.OpenAsync(Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /*/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:line 435
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
> at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlRelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SplitQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SplitQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()

Comment: Hi @XuRui can you provide the code from `_repository.FindAsync()` since the error is thrown at that moment it can be helpful to see what happens inside.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [abp.io Hangfire Cannot access a disposed context instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67371074/abp-io-hangfire-cannot-access-a-disposed-context-instance)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the right solution, use IUnitOfWork to manually start the new unit of work.

```
using (var uow = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin())
{
    await uow.CompleteAsync();
}
```